# Jenkins - Display all master branch of multiple multibranch pipeline in the same view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If you want to see the status of master branch of multibranch
pipeline, you would need to click on the pipeline.

If someone like me who has multiple multibranch pipelines, it would be extremely painful to check if anything has failed.

Is there a way to group all the master branch in one single view on the web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a view in jour jekins by hitting the '+' at the top (`http://jenkinsUrl/newView`) and select "List View".

In the Job Filters section, tick "Recurse in subfolders" and add a "Regular Expression Job Filter" :

[image: regex filter]

You can select what should match the regex according the name of your projects, but with the full name, in a multibranch pipeline, the `master` branch should be shown. That is the important think : you must match a name containing the branch.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you :).